# Binary Tree Search Not Working?

Tags: c++, tree

I'm creating a binary tree that imports a list of enzymes like this entire line

> "AarI/CACCTGCNNNN'NNNN/'NNNNNNNNGCAGGTG//"

and insertion works fine, display whats stored in the tree shows that it has correctly imported the contents from a file, but when searching for each line stored I get a return of not found except for the last insertion imported that's the only one returning true that insertion being "Zsp2I/ATGCA'T//" not sure what is wrong with the search function?

```
 template <class T>
 typename Tree<T>::node *Tree<T>::searchTree(T key)
     {
      cout << "searching for...key: " << key << endl;
       return search(key, root);
     }
 template <class T>
 typename Tree<T>::node *Tree<T>::search(T key, node*leaf)
     {
       if(leaf != NULL)
       {
        // cout << "check passed for search!" << endl;
         if(key == leaf->keyValue)
         {
            cout << "Found!" << endl;
            return leaf;
         }
         if(key < leaf->keyValue)
         {
           return search(key, leaf->left);
         }
         else
         {
           return search(key, leaf->right);
         }

       }

       else 
       {
         cout << key << " Not found...!" << endl;
         return NULL;
       }
     }
```

Fixed problem, search problem due to invisible characters upon importation of file. Fixed using a search method involving finding substrings.

```
 typename Tree<T>::node *Tree<T>::search(T key, node*leaf)
  {
    T DATA;

   if(leaf != NULL)
   {
     DATA = leaf->keyValue;


    if(DATA.find(key) != std::string::npos)
    {
       cout << "Found!" << key << endl;
       return leaf;
    }
```

Comment: Uhm... `std::set` and `std::map` are both balanced binary trees, why don't you use them?

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: Your `search` routine looks reasonable. My guess is, the problem is with insertion; it violates the assumptions that `search` makes.

Comment: I am with @IgorTandetnik on this one.

Comment: Here is example of the search being performed                           LEAF IS NOT NULL
LEAF V IS :XhoI/C'TCGAG//
key->XmaI/C'CCGGG//is greater than leaf->XhoI/C'TCGAG//
LEAF IS NOT NULL
LEAF V IS :XhoII/R'GATCY//
key->XmaI/C'CCGGG//is greater than leaf->XhoII/R'GATCY//
LEAF IS NOT NULL
LEAF V IS :XmaI/C'CCGGG//
key->XmaI/C'CCGGG//is less than leaf->XmaI/C'CCGGG//

Comment: When it reaches the correct equivalent value XmaI/C'CCGGG// the search stops but it is not confirming its existence

Answer (score 0):

Importing lines from files can lead to importation of invisible characters that will leave string comparison of identical values to return false. For my search function one approach to resolving this issue is to search within the given string with string1.find(string2) being compared to return found.